Error: URL.hostname is not implemented in React Native AWS Textract integration
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { TextractClient, AnalyzeIDCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-textract';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';

export default function App() {
  const analyzeIDDocumentFromBuffer = async (imageUri) => {
    try {
      // Read the image file into a buffer
      const imageBuffer = await RNFS.readFile(imageUri, 'base64');
      const imageBytes = Buffer.from(imageBuffer, 'base64');

      // Configure the Textract client
      const client = new TextractClient({
        region: 'us-west-2', // Replace with your desired region
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID', // Replace with your access key ID
          secretAccessKey: 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', // Replace with your secret access key
        },
      });

      // Set the parameters for the AnalyzeID command
      const params = {
        Document: {
          Bytes: imageBytes,
        },
      };

      // Create and send the AnalyzeID command
      const command = new AnalyzeIDCommand(params);
      const result = await client.send(command);
      console.log('AnalyzeID result:', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error analyzing ID document:', error);
    }
  };

  const pickImage = () => {
    const options = {
      mediaType: 'photo',
      includeBase64: false,
    };

    launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else {
        analyzeIDDocumentFromBuffer(response.assets[0].uri);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Pick an image" onPress={pickImage} />
      <Text>Check console log for the result</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

I'm encountering an error while integrating AWS Textract with a React Native application. When attempting to analyze an ID document using the AnalyzeIDCommand from the @aws-sdk/client-textract package, I'm receiving the following error message
[Error: URL.hostname is not implemented]
